# Что возвращает рекурсивная функция если в ней нет оператора return

Tags: c++

Что возвращает рекурсивная функция если в ней нет оператора return в отдельном предложении.

```
int Recur(int i = 0)
{
    if (i != 3) return Recur(++i);
}
```

Comment: Это неопределённое поведение.

Comment: можно пунктик в стандарте?

Comment: А она вообще откомпилится?

Comment: да компилируется

Comment: @Mikhailo, вроде бы предупреждение должно быть.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я об этом и говорил.

Comment: @Mikhailo, так предупреждение - значит компилируется ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Если функция, возвращаемый тип который отличен от `void`, за исключением функции `main`, заканчивается без выражения `return`, то получается Неопределённое Поведение:

> **9.6.3 The return statement [stmt.return]**
>
> 2. Flowing off the end of a constructor, a destructor, or a function with a cv `void` return type is equivalent to a `return` with no operand. Otherwise, flowing off the end of a function other than `main` (6.6.1) results in undefined behavior.

Исключение для `main` сделано специально. Эта функция может неявно возвращать 0 даже при отсутствии `return 0;` или игнорировать явно возвращаемое значение, если того требует платформа.

Comment: Я видел, как такая функция (не рекурсивная, но думаю, это дела не меняет) вообще компилировалась без возврата. В этом случае управление просто "проваливалось" в пролог кода следующей функции.